# JavaScript: Set attribute to video element

Tags: javascript

I want my javascript to take a url that user input and send to src attribute on source element but it not working. help me please?

Here is my script:

```
    <input type="text" name="aniurl" size="60"><br>
      <button class="btn" onclick="playVideo()" >button</button>
     </div>
    <video controls preload="auto" >

  <source id="anir" type="video/mp4">

 <script>

function playVideo(){
var aniurl = document.getElementsByName("aniurl")[0].value;
var ani2 = document.getElementById("anir")[0].value;
ani2.setAttribute("src",aniurl);
}

 </script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` should not be returning an array. it should be returning a specific element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ani2 = document.getElementById("anir")[0].value;`
```

should be

```
var ani2 = document.getElementById("anir");
```

`getElementById` returns a single element (or null) then `setAttribute` is a method on a dom element not a string which `value` will give you.

Also you're video tag isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ani2 = document.getElementById("anir")[0].value;
```

should be:

```
var ani2 = document.getElementById("anir").value;
```

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) does not return an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. `id="anir"` should be attached to the video tag, and not the source
   tag.
2. You must not use `[0]` after getElementById as it returns the element, not an array of elements.
3. Close the video tag properly
4. You should not use `.value` for getting the `anir` element, as you want the entire element, to set the source attribute in the subsequent line.

Final Result:

```
<input type="text" name="aniurl" id="aniurl" size="60" value="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
<button class="btn" onclick="playVideo()">button</button>

<video width="320" height="240" id="anir" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<script>
    function playVideo() {
        var aniurl = document.getElementById("aniurl").value;
        var ani2 = document.getElementById("anir");
        ani2.setAttribute("src", aniurl);
    }
</script>
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/PE4tA/)</kbd>