# onclick button to choose whether to loop audio or not

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple audio here that goes on loop.

```
<audio controls loop>
          <source src="audio.mp3">
        </audio>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to let the user choose whether to let this audio continue looping or not with a onclick button function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set/unset the `loop` attribute with javascript `document.getElementById('player_id').removeAttribute('loop')`

Comment: Hey there, your idea did work! but after I removed the loop attribute, how do I add the loop attribute again with another click of the button?

Comment: Use `setAttribute();`

Answer (score 0):

id say similar to this
[JavaScript: Set attribute to video element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215441/javascript-set-attribute-to-video-element)
because essentialy what you are doing is on click adding the autoplay attribute (likely if a check box is checked) .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

First create a button and then use this

```
document.querySelector('#btn-id').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    var player = document.querySelector('#player_id');
    if (player.hasAttribute('loop')) { 
       player.removeAttribute('loop');
    } else {
       player.setAttribute('loop','loop');
    }
}
```

replace player_id with your audio player id and replace btn-id with your button id.